# Full text search and fecet search queries in .Net for Solr

Tags: c#, solr, asp.net-mvc-5

I want the queries to query the  Apache solr in MVC nopcommerse MVC 5 application. How can I Prepare the queries for Full text search and Fecet search? I am Beginner to solr. I don't want to use solrsharp or solrnet for this purpose.

Comment: @BrianRay: I have made a local set up for Solr. Tried to check the queries from the Solr admin panel itself. But not from the Code. But I dont know how to query the solr from code for Full text and fecet search.

Answer (score 0):

You need the the solr search query that will include the ip where solr is running with port as in ... I have built the url

URL url = new URL(SOLR_SEARCH_SERVER_PROTOCOL, SOLR_SEARCH_SERVER_IP, Integer.valueOf(SOLR_SEARCH_SERVER_PORT),
            "/solr/"+cabinetId+"/select/?q="+searchText )

SOLR_SEARCH_SERVER_PROTOCOL is http(s)                                    SOLR_SEARCH_SERVER_IP : where solr is hoting             SOLR_SEARCH_SERVER_PORT : port like (8080)

if you want sorting then add &sort="+sortText                               and for faceting &facet=true&facet.field="+facetingField

Here seachText, sortText and facetingField are the params passed to the method where you construct the URL.

Note : The code syntax is of JAVA. This is only for Reference. You need to check how to build the Url in .net